# How can I add physics such as gravity to CAD files that are imported during runtime in Unreal Engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

So I am using Unreal Engines template project "Collab Viewer" that is chooseable from the "AUTOMATIVE PRODUCT DESIGN & MANUFACTURING". In this project I am using the pre-built in datasmith runtime. It is used by holding space, pressing new and choosing source. At this point the file is loaded. The thing is that it stays floating in the air. What I want is to give it gravity so that it falls to the ground.

So what I did was that I located the script where the runtime importation is handled which is with Unreal Engines visual scripting language blueprint and the file location from the root of the project is:`/Content/CollaborativeViewer/Blueprints/Commands/DataSmith/BP_DataSmith_Component.uasset`. In [image: my-image] I located this blueprint script. I think that this is the place where you can a node such as `simulate physics` to add gravity but I am not sure since I haven't worked with blueprint before. I did try around a bit with the simulate physics node, like [image: this example]. But I didn't get any result of it.

I would super appreciate help on the matter.